# selectManyCheckbox: Action will not be invoked after converter

Tags: java, jpa, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish

i would like to display all my user roles als checkboxes to assign the available roles to one user.
Therefore i created a page called userDetail.xhtml to edit the users.

```
<h:form id="form" styleClass="dialog_content">
    <p:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="noBorders">
        <p:outputLabel value="Username"/>
        <p:inputText id="input_username" value="#{userPM.userName}"/>
        <p:outputLabel value=""/>
        <p:message for="input_username"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Vorname"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{userPM.vorname}"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="Nachname"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{userPM.nachname}"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Rollen"/>
        <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{userPM.userRoles}" converter="roleConverter">
            <f:selectItems value="#{rolePM.getAllRoles()}" var="role" itemLabel="#{role.bezeichnung}" itemValue="#{role}" />
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
        <p:outputLabel />
        <p:outputLabel />

        <p:outputLabel value="Aktiv"/>
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userPM.active}"/>
        <h:outputText value="not selected" rendered="#{!userPM.active}"/>
        <p:outputLabel value=""/>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:separator/>
    <p:panelGrid style="width: 100%" styleClass="noBorders">
        <p:row>
            <p:column style="text-align: left;">
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk" value="Speichern" action="#{userPM.editUser()}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="text-align: right;">
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-closethick" value="Abbrechen" actionListener="#{userPMSuche.abortEditUser()}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

To handle the edit page, i created the following model.
The `lastUser` object will contain the user wich should be edited.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserPM implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5604907919976613472L;

    private String userName;
    private String vorname;
    private String nachname;
    private boolean active;
    private List<Role> userRoles = new ArrayList<Role>();

    private User lastUser;

    @EJB
    UserService userService;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }

    public void setVorname(String vorname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }

    public String getNachname() {
        return nachname;
    }

    public List<Role> getUserRoles() {
        return this.userRoles;
    }

    public void setNachname(String nachname) {
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }

    public boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public void setLastUser(User user) {
        this.lastUser = user;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(List<Role> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    public User getLastUser() {
        return this.lastUser;
    }

    public void editUser() {
        lastUser.setUsername(userName);
        lastUser.setVorname(vorname);
        lastUser.setNachname(nachname);
        lastUser.setUser_roles(userRoles);
        lastUser.setActive(active);
        userService.mergeUser(lastUser);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog("userDetail");
    }
}
```

I also created a converter for the roles:

```
@FacesConverter("roleConverter")
public class RoleConverter implements Converter {

    @EJB
    private RoleService roleService;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String string) {
        return roleService.getRoleByID(Integer.parseInt(string));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        if (object instanceof Role) {
            return String.valueOf(((Role) object).getId());
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

All the possible roles are displayed correctly. The `getAsString()` method is called on page load and the `getAsObject()` method is called when clicking the Save-Button (= Speichern).
But the `editUser()` method, wich is set as action behind the Save-Button will not be invoked after the `getAsObject()` method from the converter.

Am i right, that the `editUser()` method should be called after the converter by clicking the Save-Button? I also tried it with `actionListener` instead of `action`.
There is no exception printed on the console of my glassfish! The button simply not calls the action.

The aim is to select the roles for a specified user by clicking the checkboxes.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Simply means conversion failed. Put a `<p:messages/>` on your page (or look in your browser's javascript console) to confirm

Comment: Thanks for your answer colossus, but that also didn't solve my problem. I've checked these before and and also now, but there will not be printed a message on my page and also not in the console of my browser.
The above page will be included in a dialog with ajax..

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create your own `converter`.

If you want a `generic converter` then `Omnifaces SelectItemsConverter` is the best in all.

[Omni Faces Converter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter)

If you don't want to use `Omnifaces` then use below generic converter

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter(value = "entityConverter")
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {

    private static Map<Object, String> entities = new WeakHashMap<Object, String>();

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
        synchronized (entities) {
            if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                entities.put(entity, uuid);
                return uuid;
            } else {
                return entities.get(entity);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uuid) {
        for (Entry<Object, String> entry : entities.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(uuid)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Makky, but that didn't solve my problem.
I use now `Omnifaces`but when i select a item from my checkboxes, the `editUser` method to store the changes will not be invoked..